# Time span moving object blocks a beam of light.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have an object .05 inch in height that is moving at 6 inches per second past a beam of light. How long will the object block that beam of light?

I need a formula to compute the value of time a moving object will present itself in front of a beam of light .

I know that I have values of t for time, s (or v) for speed, and h for height of object - I am sure there is an equation that accounts for velocity of my object for timespan past a point in space.

**EDIT**
Beam diameter is .6mm and Half blocked is assumed as blocked.

Comment: What do you consider as a blocked beam? Does it mean 100% blocked? or half blocked is ok? Is the beam circular like a laser? The diameter of the beam of light will also be a a variable in the formula.

Comment: @Ovi edited question beam point 6mm [.6mm] and half blocked is enough to consider blocked.

Answer (score 1):

distance=rate*time.
 If you just want the time for your object to travel $0.05$ inches at $6$ inches per second, it is $\frac {0.05}{6} \approx 0.008333$ seconds.  If the beam is larger than a point the distance may be from the time the front of the object passes the front of the beam to the time the back of the object passes the back of the beam.  In that case you should subtract the diameter of the beam from the $0.05$ inch of your object.  If the beam is larger than $0.05$ inches you will never block it entirely.